# How do I decrypt an RTSPS (over TLS) stream into an RTSP stream?

Tags: ssl, gstreamer, rtsp

My goal is to use an RTSPS stream with a GStreamer pipeline. The rtspsrc element allows this, but it's much less resilient/robust than the uridecodebin element I'm currently using (and want to keep).

So I thought a proxy system might be a solution...

I did some research and apparently it would be possible with nginx or mediamtx. However, I haven't found any configuration that would allow me to achieve my goal...

What do you think?

Thanks for your help